# C#, Two lists of object find differences between one variable in both objects

Tags: c#, linq, list, object, difference

I have a program that parses two files (.txt and .xls), stores various different fields into objects

```
List<AcsRecord> Textrecords = AcsFileParser.Parsefile(path1);
List<ExcelRecord> Execelrecords = excelFileParser.Parsefile(path2);
```

As an example the AcsRecord is:

```
public string EID {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
```

Excel records has a similar Name record. I want to, in main find all of those names found in the AcsRecord that are not found in Excelrecord. Using linq join, I can only find those which are equal. I am unsure of how to reference just the name field in each record. Maybe something like !contains() ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like:

```
var excelNames = new HashSet<string>(excelRecords.Select(x => x.Name));
var textRecordsNotInExcel = textRecords.Where(t => !excelNames.Contains(t.Name))
                                       .ToList();
```

The point of creating a `HashSet<string>` here is to make the `Contains` check very cheap, by the way. A `List<string>` would work too (e.g. `var excelNames = excelRecords.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();`) but it would involve an O(N) check on all the Excel record names for each text record.

EDIT: If you only want the *names* of the text records not in Excel, it's much easier:

```
var missingNames = textRecords.Select(t => t.Name)
                              .Except(excelRecords.Select(e => e.Name))
                              .ToList();
```

Comment: awesome.  I could put this var into a foreach loop to print them to console right?

Comment: @jonskeet - Once you have the HashSet isn't if faster to use `Except()`?

Comment: @Hogan - HashSet doesn't have an `Except` method (you would use `IEnumerable.Except` which is O(n)), although  it does have `ExceptWith` but that is also O(n). HashSet.Contains is O(1) so in most case it would be more efficient to use `HashSet.Contains`, I believe.

Comment: When I attempt to print using foreach, it gives me "myclass.AcsRecord" a lot of times instead of the values (names). Why is this?

Comment: @Cassus use this `foreach(item in textRecordsNotInExcel) { print item.Name; }`

Comment: ahhh i forgot the item.Name. Thanks

Comment: @keyboardP - that makes sense, I was looking at it backwards

Comment: @Cassus: I thought you *wanted* the items. If you only want the names, it's easier. (I'll edit to show that.)

Comment: @Cassus: If you only care about the names, why would you need the right number of duplicates? It's not like you can tell which one corresponds to which text record anyway. If you're going to keep changing the requirements, please be more specific about them.

Comment: Both of your answers work well and I  understand the differences between them, thank you. I now know more because there are two methods given. I did originally state that I wanted the names. Also, I may use the first method you suggested because there are other elements to my program that I did not provide. I have gotten the information I needed to move on without providing it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you are right, you should `!Contains()` like this way:

```
var query= from ar in Textrecords
           let er=Excelrecords.Select(r=>r.Name)
           where !er.Contains(ar.Name)
           select ar;
```